# Serilog: cannot log to MongoDb using MongoDb sink

Tags: .net, mongodb, serilog

I have a local MongoDb database instance (created by running mongod from the Windows command line), and a simple console program that tries to log a string to the MongoDb database using Serilog and its MongoDb sink:

```
        var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.ColoredConsole()
            .WriteTo.MongoDB("mongodb://localhost/mydb")
            .CreateLogger();

        log.Fatal("Fatal message");
```

The "Fatal message" message is written correctly to the console, but not to my MongoDb database.

My current MongoDb database is "mydb". According to "show collections", I only have collections system.indexes and testData, and "db.testData.find()" produces nothing.

The Serilog site says to use connection string "mongo://mydb/log", but that throws an exception "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in MongoDB.Driver.dll". The connection string I used in my code is specified on the MongoDb site, at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/

How can I log to MongoDb using Serilog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible that you're just experiencing the default (two second?) buffering delay - if you close a console app in Windows it hard-terminates the program so buffers can't always be flushed. Waiting a few seconds before closing the app will fix this if so.

Otherwise, the way to tackle all sink debugging in Serilog is to set `SelfLog.Out`:

```
SelfLog.Out = Console.Error;
```

This will print any exceptions raised by the sink, allowing you to zoom in on the error pretty quickly if that's where it is.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. Is there a way to set the buffering delay to 0? That will make testing so much easier.

Comment: Passing `period: TimeSpan.Zero` should do it.

Comment: (Though a few milliseconds may be more sane - zero's totally untested IIRC :))

Comment: Where do I pass the "period: TimeSpan.Zero"? Could you give a code example please?

Comment: `.WriteTo.MongoDB("mongodb://localhost/mydb", period: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1))`

Comment: Thanks. I tried this with TimeSpan.Zero, which works fine. Would like to suggest to either make Zero the default, or to mention the default buffering delay in the Serilog introductory documentation (plus how to switch it off).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at how we can make the delay more obvious. Turning it off obliterates performance for frequent network writes. Cheers!

Comment: Tried TimeSpan.Zero in an NUnit test using the RavenDB sink and it worked, but had an odd side-effect.  It caused the nunit-agent.exe process to start using 80-100% CPU continuously after the test was run in the NUnit GUI test runner.  The test runner was still responsive and could either run other tests or just sit idle, but had to be shut down to get the process to stop the excessive CPU usage.  No CPU issue in VS2013 Test Explorer, and no issue in either when using TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1) instead.

Comment: Note: updated syntax for turning on the Serilog debugging is SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);

Answer (score 2):

I took the answers by Nicholas and redwards (thanks to both of you!), did some more experimenting, and captured the results at:
http://jsnlog.com/Documentation/GetStartedLogging/StructuredLogging

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, I was getting the exact same error until I switched the connection string to be

**mongodb://myMachineName/mydb**

Before, I had mongo://localhost/mydb.

But while mongo vs mongodb solved the Exception problem, it wasn't inserting records into mydb! So I changed it to

**.WriteTo.MongoDB("mongodb://localhost/logs", restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Verbose)**

and now it is working! "logs" was created with "log" as a collection which held the JSON data.